# [uwsgi + lua]: no app loaded

Tags: lua, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up a uWSGI server with Lua script.

For now I've just a little test script (more or less the one shown in the uWSGI doc http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Lua.html#your-first-wsapi-application).

Here is my script :

```
function run(wsapi_env)
  local headers = { ["Content-type"] = "text/html" }
  local function hello_text()
    coroutine.yield("<html><body>")
    coroutine.yield("<p>Hello Wsapi!</p>")
    coroutine.yield("<p>PATH_INFO: " .. wsapi_env.PATH_INFO .. "</p>")
    coroutine.yield("<p>SCRIPT_NAME: " .. wsapi_env.SCRIPT_NAME .. "</p>")
    coroutine.yield("</body></html>")
  end
  return 200, headers, coroutine.wrap(hello_text)
end

return run
```

I launch uWSGI with this command line ( until I manage to launch it succefully once, then I will use config file) :

```
uwsgi --socket :63031 --plugins lua --lua main.lua --master
```

I've run this command from the directory where is stored main.lua (I've tried with main.lua full path ) .
But uWSGI doesn't load the lua script :

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.7-debian (64bit) on [Thu Feb  5 15:45:00 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.1 on 25 October 2014 19:17:54
os: Linux-3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1 (2014-12-08)
nodename: ns342653.ip-91-121-135.eu
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /home/vincent/web
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
your processes number limit is 63906
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 65536
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :63031 fd 3
Initializing Lua environment... (1 lua_States)
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 8148)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 8149, cores: 1)
```

How can I make uWSGI load my script ?

Thanks for your awnser.

( P.S. : I've successfully launched uWSGI with psgi and perl script with almost the same config)

Comment: The lua plugin is not very "chatty".  Very probably your app has been loaded (albeit the "no app loaded"). Just try calling it (ensure the right modifier is set in the webserver). The plugin is solid, but was never ported to the full 2.0 api, that is why some internal structure is messy.

Comment: what do you mean by "right modifier" ? I've tried with --http-socket-modifier1 6 (what uWSGI propose me when I tried --http-modifier1 6). And how do I call my app ? I've tried to call it within lua interpreter and print run function return values (to see if they were consistent), but it print function adress ...
Its the first time I try web development (and I'm learning lua), I don't know very well how everything works, excuse for asking stupid question...

Comment: oh, and when I try to reach the webpage, I've got `(101) Network is unreachable`

Comment: For http mode: "uwsgi --http-socket :9090 --plugin lua --lua foo.lua --http-socket-modifier1 6" For uwsgi mode: uwsgi --socket :9090 --plugin lua --lua foo.lua" then in your webserver set the modifier to use (in nginx it is uwsgi_modifier1 6;)

Comment: It works ! I had forgotten that there is an parameter in nginx conf file to tell the http-modifier ... Now that I've corrected it, it works (it was still uwsgi_modifier1 5 since I configured it for perl, sometime I can be stupid).
Thanks for your help !